# can not run meteor bundle in node on CENTOS

Tags: centos, meteor, centos6

I have a meteor app that works fine on my computer under OSX but when I copy it to my CENTOS 6 server it gives me following error:

```
node main.js 

server/server.js:95
  Fiber(function () {
  ^
ReferenceError: Fiber is not defined
    at run (/root/bundle/server/server.js:95:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/bundle/server/server.js:156:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
    at require (module.js:378:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/bundle/main.js:1:63)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
```

I did install the fibers package with `npm install fibers`

I also changed the port number in server.js to be 8282 instead of 80 in order to avoid any conflicts.

thank you for your help

Comment: Can you post output of `npm install fibers`. Also, did you try installing it with the -g option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it turns out you have to install fibers inside the meteor project and not as a global package